# Problemas con CRUD en java Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, crud, nullpointerexception

¡Buenas gente!

El problema es el siguiente, a la hora de agregar un cliente aveces se agrega y aveces tira el error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. La verdad que no se por qué es, intente buscar soluciones en google pero parece que es un error que se resuelve de muchas formas y la mayoría de veces no entiendo lo que dicen.

Tengo 3 forms, se los dejo a continuación.

FORM1:

```
public class Form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   
    public Form1() {
        initComponents();
        cargartabla();
    }

                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TblCl1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnActualizar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Clientes");

        TblCl1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Nombre de Cliente", "Dni", "Id De Cliente"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TblCl1);

        jButton1.setText("Agregar Cliente");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Buscar cliente");

        jButton3.setText("Filtrar");

        jButton4.setText("Inspeccionar Cliente");

        jButton5.setText("Inspeccionar Table de Clientes");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnActualizar.setText("Actualizar tabla");
        btnActualizar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnActualizarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

                             

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
               
        Form2 abrir = new Form2();
        abrir.setVisible(true);
        
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Form3 abrir = new Form3();
        abrir.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    private void btnActualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        cargartabla();
    }                                             

    private void cargartabla(){
    
        DefaultTableModel modelotabla = (DefaultTableModel) TblCl1.getModel();
        modelotabla.setRowCount(0);
        
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        int columnas;
    
        try{
            Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Nombre_Cliente,DNI,ID_Cliente FROM Clientes");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            columnas = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            
            while (rs.next()){
            Object[] fila = new Object[columnas];
            for (int indice=0; indice<columnas; indice++){
                fila[indice] = rs.getObject(indice+1);
            }
            modelotabla.addRow(fila);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        
    }
   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Form1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
              
}
```

FORM2:

```
public class Form2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Form2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    
                           
    private void initComponents() {

        txtNombreCliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtDNI = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtTelefono = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtDireccion = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtAuto = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Nombre de Cliente");

        jLabel2.setText("Dni");

        jLabel3.setText("Telefono");

        jLabel4.setText("Direccion");

        jLabel5.setText("Auto");

        jLabel6.setText("Agregar Cliente");

        jButton1.setText("Guardar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(txtNombreCliente)
                        .addComponent(txtAuto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 196, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(txtDireccion)
                        .addComponent(txtTelefono)
                        .addComponent(txtDNI)))
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtNombreCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtDNI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(txtTelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtDireccion, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtAuto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String Nombre_Cliente = txtNombreCliente.getText();
        int DNI = Integer.parseInt(txtDNI.getText());
        int Telefono = Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText());
        String Direccion = txtDireccion.getText();
        String Auto = txtAuto.getText();
        
        if (Form3.txtComparar.getText().equals("0")){
            try{
            Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Clientes(Nombre_Cliente,DNI,Telefono,Direccion,Auto) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, Nombre_Cliente);
            ps.setInt(2, DNI);
            ps.setInt(3, Telefono);
            ps.setString(4, Direccion);
            ps.setString(5, Auto);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            limpiar();
            Form1.btnActualizar.doClick();
            Form3.btnActualizar2.doClick();
            Form3.txtComparar.setText("0");
            this.setVisible(false);
            } catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
            }
        } else if (Form3.txtComparar.getText().equals("1")){
            try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(Form3.txtPID.getText());
            Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Clientes SET Nombre_Cliente=?,DNI=?,Telefono=?,Direccion=?,Auto=? WHERE ID_Cliente=?");
            ps.setString(1, Nombre_Cliente);
            ps.setInt(2, DNI);
            ps.setInt(3, Telefono);
            ps.setString(4, Direccion);
            ps.setString(5, Auto);
            ps.setInt(6,id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            limpiar();
            Form1.btnActualizar.doClick();
            Form3.btnActualizar2.doClick();
            Form3.txtComparar.setText("0");
            this.setVisible(false);
            } catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
            }
        }
    }                                        

    public void limpiar(){
    txtNombreCliente.setText("");
    txtDNI.setText("");
    txtTelefono.setText("");
    txtDireccion.setText("");
    txtAuto.setText("");
    }
    
  
        
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Form2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
                
}
```

FORM3:

```
public class Form3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   
    public Form3() {
        initComponents();
        cargartabla();
    }

 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TblCl2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnModificar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtComparar = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnActualizar2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TblCl2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Id", "Nombre De Cliente", "DNI", "Auto", "Direccion", "Fecha de Emision", "Fecha de Renovacion", "Fecha de Nacimiento"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TblCl2);

        jButton1.setText("Agregar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Borrar");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnModificar.setText("Modificar");
        btnModificar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnModificarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Volver");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtComparar.setEditable(false);
        txtComparar.setText("0");

        txtPID.setEditable(false);

        btnActualizar2.setText("Actualizar");
        btnActualizar2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnActualizar2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 926, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnModificar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnActualizar2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(txtComparar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtPID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 49, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(btnModificar)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(txtComparar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtPID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnActualizar2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Form2 abrir = new Form2();
        abrir.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Form2 abrir = new Form2();
        abrir.setVisible(true);
        txtComparar.setText("1");
        try{
            int fila = TblCl2.getSelectedRow();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(TblCl2.getValueAt(fila,0).toString());
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ResultSet rs;
            String pid= String.valueOf(id);
            txtPID.setText(pid);
            
            Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Nombre_Cliente,DNI,Telefono,Direccion,Auto FROM Clientes WHERE ID_Cliente=?");
            ps.setInt(1,id);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
            Form2.txtNombreCliente.setText(rs.getString("Nombre_cliente"));
            Form2.txtDNI.setText(rs.getString("DNI"));
            Form2.txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("Telefono"));
            Form2.txtDireccion.setText(rs.getString("Direccion"));
            Form2.txtAuto.setText(rs.getString("Auto"));
            
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
        }
    }                                            

    private void btnActualizar2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        cargartabla();
    }                                              

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Form1 abrir = new Form1();
        abrir.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         
      int fila = TblCl2.getSelectedRow();  
      int id = Integer.parseInt(TblCl2.getValueAt(fila,0).toString());  
      cargartabla();
      try{
          Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
          PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Clientes WHERE ID_Cliente=?");
          ps.setInt(1,id);
          ps.executeUpdate();
          
      }catch(SQLException e){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
      }
    }                                        
    
    private void cargartabla(){
    
        DefaultTableModel modelotabla = (DefaultTableModel) TblCl2.getModel();
        modelotabla.setRowCount(0);
        
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        int columnas;
    
        try{
            Connection con = Conexion.getconexion();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID_Cliente,Nombre_Cliente,DNI,Auto,Direccion FROM Clientes");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            columnas = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            
            while (rs.next()){
            Object[] fila = new Object[columnas];
            for (int indice=0; indice<columnas; indice++){
                fila[indice] = rs.getObject(indice+1);
            }
            modelotabla.addRow(fila);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form3.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Form3().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }                  
}
```

Tuve que quitar algunas lineas porque la publicación me decía que me excedí con los caracteres, intente quitar cosas irrelevantes.
Espero que me pueda ayudar, estuve toda el día intentado resolverlo pero no hay manera. Les pido disculpas si el código esta desordenado, estuve siguiendo un video en youtube y modificandolo para lo que necesitaba. Hay muchas lineas que no comprendo todavía

Comment: Hola, deberías poner en que parte del código te arroja error; haciendo una revisión rápida de tu código en la clase ``Form1`` metodo ``cargartabla`` terminando el while(rs.next()) falta la linea de código TblCl1.setModel(modelotabla)

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo! El problema era que en el if que tengo en el Form2 hay un compararText que se declara en el Form3 entonces cuando intentaba guardar datos sin haber habierto el Form3 tomaba el compararText como null.